# How to write an inner join query to retrieve all records of three tables in Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I want to retrieve all records from 3 tables: Personal_Info, Address, and Fitness. I have primary key as CandidateID in Personal_Info table and foreign key as CandidateID in Address table and UserID in Fitness table.

I have written inner query as below which seems to be incorrect as I am not getting all the records from three tables.

```
public void getAllRecords()
{
int searchId = 1;
Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String query = "FROM Address as a, Fitness as f inner join a.personalInfo as p inner join f.personalInfo as p where p.candidateID=:userID";
Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery(query);
theQuery.setParameter("userID", searchId);

List<?> list = theQuery.list();
         for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                Object[] row = (Object[]) list.get(i);
                System.out.println("Record"+i+": "+row[i]);
         }
}
```

How can I correct this inner query?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join all the three tables using CandidateID.
Try this:

```
FROM Address as a, Fitness as f, Personal_Info as p
WHERE p.CandidateID = a.CandidateID
AND p.CandidateID = f.UserID
```

Comment: This query doesn't work as it is unable to find 'CandidateID' from Address &Fitness tables. I have one to one mapping in entity table for these foreign keys. For example: 
 @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="CandidateID_FK")
 private PersonalInfo personalInfo;
 
I have written query in DAO impl class as below:
 String query = "FROM Address a JOIN PersonalInfo p ON a.CandidateID_FK = p.candidateID JOIN Fitness f ON f.CandidateID_FK1 = p.candidateID";

Error in console:

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: CandidateID_FK

Comment: Also tried below query but it is not giving any output -
  FROM Fitness as f, Address as a, PersonalInfo as p inner join f.personalInfo as fp inner join a.personalInfo as ap

Comment: @JayeshB can you share the table structure?

Comment: Table :1
CREATE TABLE `personal_info` (
  `CandidateID` int(11) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`CandidateID`))

Table :2
CREATE TABLE `address_details` (
  `AddressID` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `CandidateID_idx` (`CandidateID`),
  CONSTRAINT `CandidateID` FOREIGN KEY (`CandidateID`) REFERENCES `personal_info` (`CandidateID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) 

Table :3
CREATE TABLE `fitness_details` (
  `FitnessID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `UserID` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `personal_info` (`CandidateID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

Comment: @JayeshB According to your table structure, column name CandidateID_FK and CandidateID_FK1 does not exists in any table.

Hence the error, org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: CandidateID_FK